# deactivated touchpad - how to activate?

Tags: touchpad

I just mindlessly deactivated my touchpad in Ubuntu 13.04 through the gnome-control-center and have no clue how to activate it again without the use of the touchpad.

Also `synclient Touchpadoff=0` doesn't change anything.

Comment: just found the "xinput list" command. will try it now.

Comment: looked for the device in xinput list and tried to activate it via "xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 1" ... didn't change anythig.

Comment: Do you mean re-enabling it from control center doesn’t work?

Comment: since I have no input device to move the cursor it doesn't.

Comment: Extremely embarrassed...

I had a mouse here that didn't work at all on the surface I was using it on. Got the mouse on a proper Mousepad -> activated the Touchpad through the gnome-control-center -> Everything is fine again. 

Thanks anyway ...

Comment: :D You could use your keyboard to switch it ON. Know for future: *Alt+F10* opens top menus. When you went to System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad, you can use Tab key to select the switch and Space to toggle. However I wonder why `xinput` didn’t work!

Comment: @AliNa You could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, let’s be presice. If you disable/switch OFF your touchpad through System Settings (Gnome Control Center) you can’t re-enable it with `xinput`! When you have no other mouse or pointer device, you have to go to System Settings using your **keyboard**.

Fortunately, Unity is well designed for both keyboard and mouse, so without a mouse you can still do everything. For example, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open top menu and then navigate to System Settings with arrow keys. Or simply press <kbd>Super</kbd>(or <kbd></kbd>) to open the Dash and search for *mouse*. Select it with down arrow key (<kbd>↓</kbd>) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open.

[image: Search for mouse in Dash]

Finally **using <kbd>Tab</kbd>** select the Touchpad switch – the orange box around the switch shows that you’re on the right place. Toggle it ON by hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Switch OFF]

Comment: Tabbing in the mouse/trackpad screen does not highlight anything in Ubuntu 16.10. I had to do `tab+enter` a bunch of times until it eventually selected the ON button -- but it was not showing me which object was highlighted. Probably a bug.

Comment: While this 'looks' like a solution it doesn't work in reality for modern versions. Ubuntu 16.10 magically skips the On/Off button for touchpad.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.10 & pure terminal solution, see the post below about "gsettings"

Answer (score 28):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I had to use from the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled
```

To get to the Terminal I used the command key and then typed in "terminal" and hit enter. Hope this helps someone else caught with their mouse down.

Comment: You are one awesome person. Thank you so much. It just worked out for me.:)

Comment: That's the winning answer.

Comment: That's the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Tabbing in the mouse/trackpad screen does not highlight anything in Ubuntu 16.10 for me (brand new install).

I had to do `tab+enter` a bunch of times until it eventually selected the ON button and enabled it -- but it was not showing me which object was highlighted. Probably a bug.

Comment: This must replace the accepted answer.

Comment: I found the same thing in Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome.  After I disabled the touch pad, that part of the mouse/trackpad settings was no longer displayed so I couldn't see an option to reenable it.  Rebooting didn't help.

Comment: You're a saviour! Spent 1 hour in a cafe just trying to get the touchpad back working.

Answer (score 4):

I have Linux Mint 18 installed with kernel 4.4.0-45. I did the following to make it easy to toggle the touchpad state.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xinput

$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ **FTE1001:00 0B05:0101**               ***id=14***   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

- Look for the id of the touchpad, in my case it's 14. I wrote a small shell script to turn the touchpad off and on.
- TouchPad off:

  ```
  $ cd /usr/local/bin
  $ sudo nano touchpad-off

  #!/bin/bash
  # touchpad off
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
  echo touchpad off
  ```
- TouchPad on:

  ```
  $ cd /usr/local/bin
  $ sudo nano touchpad-on

  #!/bin/bash
  # touchpad on
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
  echo touchpad on
  ```
- Make the scripts executable with:

  ```
  chmod +x touchpad-off
  chmod +x touchpad-on
  ```

  Now you can easily toggle the touchpad state with `touchpad-off` and `touchpad-on` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the <kbd>**Menu**</kbd> key on your keyboard.
2. Navigate down to the *Change Desktop Background* option and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, navigate to the "all settings" page and the search field.
4. Type `Mouse` and use <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to select it.
5. Use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to go down to the toggle switch in the Touchpad section, and use <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to mark it as on.

Your touchpad should be re-enabled.

Comment: To save on a lot of steps, you can also use the Win/Meta key, type `Mouse`, hit enter, and then use TAB to navigate down to the touchpad toggle, which is exactly what the accepted answer says.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that xinput works the best for switching touchpad on/off on my linux mint 18.3 Jumper Ezbook 3 Pro (4.10.0.38 kernel) versus using GUI System setings -> Mouse and touchpad -> Touchpad -> On/Off slider

I used script provided in above answer by Seth Bergman, but wanted to share 2 improvements to it.

1) Id of the device sometimes change, so you cant have it like fixed number in your script. Sometimes id=14, and sometimes 15.

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]

```
#!/bin/bash
# touchpad off
DeviceID=$(xinput -list | grep Touchpad | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/id=//')
xinput --set-prop $DeviceID "Device Enabled" 1
echo touchpad on
```

Of course you should change  'Touchpad' to the name or number of your Touchpad Device. That way, whatever the device id becomes, the script will always work.

2) You can make a shortcut to your scripts to use them quickly. In Linux Mint you should go to the Menu -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts -> Add Custom Shortcut. In command field just paste the path to your script file like that: /usr/local/bin/touchpad-on and name of choice.

And the add key-bindings of choise.

et voilà!