# How to turn my touchpad back on in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 16.10

I turned my touchpad off on my laptop from the system settings.  This was because I had a mouse plugged into my USB Hub and the touchpad bugged my occasionally.  I almost immediately realized that I'd need to turn it back on before going mobile with my laptop where I wouldn't have a mouse.

When I tried to turn it back on, I noticed that there were no touchpad settings in the system settings mouse area anymore, gone, not there.

I tried xinput list, but the touchpad wasn't in the list.  I tried the synclient command with no luck.

The mouse still works fine, but I can't turn the touchpad back on.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have recycled the system several times and that didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/335317/deactivated-touchpad-how-to-activate , see if this helps or not

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I found it inactivated in the bios.  I activated it there and it reappears (obviously) in the system settings where I was able to turn it back on.