# How to turn on Touchpad in setting on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, touchpad

I was making some tweaks in my touchpad settings. Then by mistake I turned the touchpad OFF. Now I don't have a spare mouse and My touchpad isn't working. How can I turn that back ON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159397/how-to-enable-touchpad) and [deactivated touchpad - how to activate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335317/deactivated-touchpad-how-to-activate/335500)